# Serailising Umbraco settings to the file system and packaging changes for deployment

Tags: asp.net, deployment, content-management-system, umbraco, version-control

Does anybody know of an easy way to serialise Umbraco settings (Document Types, Media Types etc) to the file system in order to manage that data within source control?

Note: changes to settings made on the file system need to be easily integrated back into the CMS database.

Also, does anybody know of a way to package up settings from a development environment for rolling out to staging and live environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back through my unanswered questions, providing updates where possible.

For reference, you can use uSync to serialise content from Umbraco:

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync

Comment: You shouldn't post links as answers. If the link changes or the site goes offline, you answer becomes useless. Instead, use the info to build the answer and post the link as reference only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method currently other than rolling your own package to do it but it should be relatively straight forward using the API. Check out the "[Backing up Document Types](http://www.farmcode.org/post/2010/06/11/Backing-up-Document-Types.aspx)" article as a starting point .

Your second point about deployment was something discussed in an open session at the Umbraco Codegarden this year and no conclusion was made that was a one answer fits all.

Comment: Interesting blog post, thanks.

For deploying changes, I was hoping that there was a similar method to Sitecore's packaging which allows the developer to zip data types, pages etc to install on other instances.

Comment: You can do this using the Umbraco Package manager in the developer section however my response was in relation to your original question about storing the document types in source control. Creating a package with these items will tie them all into a single file rather than exporting the doctypes to the file system as individual files.